# document.getElementByID is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, getelementbyid

I'm learning jQuery and was following a tutorial, a very strange error has perplexed me.
Here's my html :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title> Simple Task List </title>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="task-list.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <ul id="tasks">

    </ul>
      <input type="text" id="task-text" />
      <input type="submit" id="add-task" />
  </body>
</html>
```

and The jQuery :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //To add a task when the user hits the return key
    $('#task-text').keydown(function(evt){
      if(evt.keyCode == 13)
      {
        add_task(this, evt);
      }
      });
    //To add a task when the user clicks on the submit button
      $("#add-task").click(function(evt){
        add_task(document.getElementByID("task-text"),evt);
        });
    });

function add_task(textBox, evt){
  evt.preventDefault();
  var taskText = textBox.value;
  $("<li>").text(taskText).appendTo("#tasks");
  textBox.value = "";
};
```

When I add elements By hitting the return key, there's no problem.
But When I click the Submit Button then firebug shows this error

```
document.getElementByID is not a function
[Break On This Error] add_task(document.getElementByID("task-text"),evt);
task-list.js (line 11)
```

I tried to use jQuery instead replacing it with

```
$("#task-text")
```

This time the error is :

```
$("<li>").text(taskText).appendTo is not a function
[Break On This Error] $("<li>").text(taskText).appendTo("#tasks");
task-list.js (line 18
which results in the following error
```

I've been trying to debug this for some time but i just don't get it. Its probably a really silly mistake that i've made. Any help is most appreciated.

Edit :
I'm using jQuery 1.6.1

Comment: Off-topic: If you're learning jQuery, FYI, you very rarely if ever want to use `document.getElementById`. The jQuery equivalent is [the `$` (or `jQuery`) function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) with an ID selector. jQuery actually works around bugs in `getElementById` on some browsers, so if you're using the library, it's best to *use* it. :-) (Not saying you shouldn't know what `getElementById` is, though.)

Comment: if you are using jQuery then why you are using the classic javascript syntax i.e. getElementById . YOu should use $('#id') syntax.

Answer (score 158, accepted):

It's `document.getElementById()` and not `document.getElementByID()`. Check the casing for `Id`.

Comment: For me it's `Document.getElementById()`

Comment: Any reason why this is case sensitive?

Answer (score 44):

In my case, I was using it on an `element` instead of `document`, and according to MDN:

> Unlike some other element-lookup methods such as Document.querySelector() and Document.querySelectorAll(), getElementById() is only available as a method of the global document object, and not available as a method on all element objects in the DOM. Because ID values must be unique throughout the entire document, there is no need for "local" versions of the function.

Comment: useful reference article: https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/javascript-typeerror-getelementbyid-is-not-a-function

Answer (score 24):

It's `getElementById()`

Note the lower-case `d` in `Id`.

Answer (score 4):

The error *`document.getElementByID is not a function`* indicates a syntactic error.

You need to replace the errorprone *`D`* as in `document.getElementByID()` with `document.getElementById()`

Likewise,

- To find HTML Elements by Tag Name: `document.getElementsByTagName("p")`
- To find HTML Elements by Class Name: `document.getElementsByClassName("classname")`
- To find HTML Element by CSS Selectors: `document.querySelectorAll("p.introduction")`

Answer (score 3):

I've modified your script to work with jQuery, if you wish to do so.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //To add a task when the user hits the return key
    $('#task-text').keydown(function(evt){
          if(evt.keyCode == 13)
          {
             add_task($(this), evt);
          }
    });
    //To add a task when the user clicks on the submit button
    $("#add-task").click(function(evt){
        add_task($("#task-text"),evt);
    });
});

function add_task(textBox, evt){
  evt.preventDefault();
  var taskText = textBox.val();
  $("<li />").text(taskText).appendTo("#tasks");
  textBox.val("");
};
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several things wrong with this as you can see in the other posts, but the reason you're getting that error is because you name your form getElementById. So document.getElementById now points to your form instead of the default method that javascript provides. See my fiddle for a working demo https://jsfiddle.net/jemartin80/nhjehwqk/.

```
function checkValues()
{
   var isFormValid, form_fname;

   isFormValid = true;
   form_fname = document.getElementById("fname");
   if (form_fname.value === "")
   {
       isFormValid = false;
   }
   isFormValid || alert("I am indicating that there is something wrong with your input.")

   return isFormValid;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It worked like this for me:

```
document.getElementById("theElementID").setAttribute("src", source);
document.getElementById("task-text").innerHTML = "";
```

Change the

```
getElementById("theElementID")
```

for your element locator (name, css, xpath...)

Answer (score 0):

if you are using jQuery, it's  `jQuery("#my_id")`

if you are using raw javascript, it's `document.getElementById('my_id')`, remember that the parameter should not contain `#`.