# Why is document.getElementByID throwing an error?

Tags: javascript, html

Currently trying to write a script which will allow a website to add a users email to a mailing list for a newsletter (its in the early stages)

Everytime I run the code I am getting the following error:

```
Newsletter.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementByID is not a function
    at Newsletter.js:2
    at Newsletter.js:11
```

I understand that this is having an issue at line 2 and 11, I just cannot see what the issue is.

I have included all relevant HTML and CSS.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

The form is located in the footer area so I have just included the footer for HTML:

```
<footer class="container-fluid text-center">
    <p id="TestSubmit">Online Store Copyright</p>  
    <form class="form-inline" id = "NewsletterEmail">Get deals:
            <input type="email" class="form-control" size="50" 
            placeholder="Email Address" id="EmailAddress">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="Submit">Sign 
    Up</button>
    </form>

    <script src="JS/Utilities.js"></script>
    <script src="JS/Newsletter.js"></script>
</footer>

function addEvent(el, event, callback) {
    if ('addEventListener' in el) {                     
        el.addEventListener(event, callback, false);    
    } else {                                            
        el['e' + event + callback] = callback;          
        el[event + callback] = function() {             
            el['e' + event + callback](window.event);   
        };
        el.attachEvent('on' + event, el [event + callback]);
    }
}

(function(){
    var form = document.getElementByID('NewsletterEmail'); 

    addEvent(form, 'Submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var elements = this.elements;
        var email = elements.email.value;
        var msg = 'Welcome ' + username;
        document.getElementByID('TestSubmit').textContent = msg;
    });
}());
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [document.getElementByID is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6409505/document-getelementbyid-is-not-a-function)

Comment: Check this [getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById). not `getElementByID`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var form = document.getElementById('NewsletterEmail');
```

This is the correct one, not ID but Id.

Comment: Just an advice. Its a bad practice to answer a typographical question.

Answer (score 1):

it's `getElementById` not `getElementByID`

```
var form = document.getElementById('NewsletterEmail');
```