# Need help getting input to return and print if empty from a form

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get my code to print in the console display if my user ID contains the right parameters, and my first and last name inputs to print invalid first or last name if left empty, but it keeps saying that my functions aren't functions. Here is the code below

```js
const validateUserId = (userId) => /^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9]).{8,12}$/.test(userId);
const validateUserFname = (firstName) => /^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])$/.test(firstName);

const form = document.getElementById("myForm");

form.onsubmit = (e) => {
  // stop page from reload
  e.preventDefault();

  // validate userid and set message
  if (validateUserId(e.target.elements.uid.value)) {
    document.getElementById("validate ID").innerHTML = "Valid User ID";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("validate ID").innerHTML = "Invalid UserID";

  }
  if (validateUserFname(e.target.elements.fname.value)) {
    document.getElementById("validate Fname").innerHTML = "Valid First NAme";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("validate Fname").innerHTML = "Invalid Fname";
  }
}
```

```html
<form id="myForm" action="">
  <label for="uid">User Id:</label>
  <input type="name" id="uid" name="uid"><br>
  <label for="fname"> First Name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br>
  <label for="lname">Last name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname"><br>
  <label for="birthday"> Birthday:</label>
  <input type="date" id="birthday" name="birthday"><br>
  <input type="submit" id="accept" value="Accept">
</form>

<div id="validate ID"></div>
<div id="validate Fname"></div>
```

Comment: You have typo at the end `getElementByID`. It should be  `getElementById`

Comment: As side note, use `textContent` instead of `innerhTML`. `innerHTML` is slow because it needs the DOM to reparse and poses a security issue (XSS injection). Also a `ternary conditional operator` would rais performance and make the code faster: `document.getElementById('validate ID').textContent = (validateUserId(e.target.elements.uid.value)) ? 'Valid User ID' : 'Invalid User ID';`

Comment: Duplicate of [document.getElementByID is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6409505)

Comment: @tacoshy I don't think there's any great reason to consider "performance" here. Better to focus on readability; get the input value, validate and set a string based on validation, set the DOM content w/ that string.